# How to create watermark in image just like Google maps watermarks

Tags: java, watermark

How to create watermark in image just like Google maps watermarks ? I mean transparency style.

Comment: Do some research into BufferedImage, ImageIO, AlphaComposite and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Load the original image...

```
BufferedImage source = ImageIO.load(...);
```

Load the water mark...

```
BufferedImage waterMark = ImageIO.load(...);
```

Grab a `Graphics` context from the `source`...

```
Graphics2D g2d = source.createGraphics();
```

Create a `AlphaComposite`

```
g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0.5f));
```

Draw the `waterMark` onto the `source`...

```
g2d.drawImage(waterMark, x, y, null);
```

Clean up...

```
g2d.dispose();
```

Take a look at:

- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)
- [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)
- [Writing/Saving an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html)

for more details

Comment: thanks for the reply. But if you check the google watermark it is not just a simple transparency setting. It is image processing per each pixel color to indicate the target color.

Comment: AlphaComposite offers other composites, you could try playing with some of those, but you'd need to generate a transparent image first